# What Files to Include in GitHub Repository and what Format to Use?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, repository

I am currently in the process of uploading a Java Eclipse project to a new repository here on GitHub and had a question about the proper files to include and the format the repository should have when uploading. I have done some research on other users repositories seeing that they have the .gitignore, .gitattributes, .classpath, .project, and .settings files. I also didn't know what the proper format would be on using folders for src, bin, test, etc. If you could send some answers my way about this issue that would be great.

Eventually I will be uploading another Java Eclipse project here that is using Web Services and would like the same information listed above for this type of project.

If there are specific formats and or guidelines for the falling type of projects as well please send that information over:

1.) API
2.) Desktop Apps
3.) Web Services
4.) Java Server Pages
5.) Mobile Apps

I will attach some screenshots in hopes to give you an idea about what I am talking about.

In the screenshot included the format I am referencing is how he has the folders listed in order.
Example:

```
src
.gitignore
.travis.yml
LICENSE.MD
README.MD
nbactions.xml
pom.xml
```

Example Repository:

[image]

Thanks so much!

Comment: I'd recommend using a maven or gradle project. IDE-specific project-files are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, I'd recommend including the .project, .settings and .classpath that make your Eclipse project configuration shared and more easily reusable by others. The bin/ and target/ folders are usually the only ones that should be excluded.